# How can I make my guess-password code's loop work?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to write this function "guessPasscode", but don't think my codes work. (the other functions are correct) It is supposed to guess every number from 0000 ~ 9999 as four-digit passcodes.

I run the function and it doesn't print out anything, and I also don't think the function works the way I wanted it to.

```
var guess = "";
var guessCode ="";
function start() {
    var secretPasscode = generateRandomPasscode();
    guessPasscode(secretPasscode);


}

// Checks whether the given guess passcode is the correct passcode
function isCorrect(guessCode, correctCode) {
    return guessCode == correctCode;
}

// Generates a random 4 digit passcode and returns it as a String
function generateRandomPasscode() {
    var randomPasscode = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var randomDigit = Randomizer.nextInt(0, 9);
        randomPasscode += randomDigit;
    }

    return randomPasscode;
}
function guessPasscode(secretPasscode){
    for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        guess += a;
        for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++){
            guess += b;
            for(var c = 0; c < 10; c++){
                guess += c;
                for (var d = 0; d < 10; d++){
                    guess += d;
                    if (isCorrect(guessCode, secretPasscode)){
                    println("Success!");
                    break;
                    }
                    guess = 0; //I am not sure about this line though
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (isCorrect(guessCode, secretPasscode)){
        println("Success!");
    }
}
```

I expect it to print "success" and stop the loop after it has found the correct password.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: Same as like Car is to Carpet

Comment: why four loops when you can just count from 0 to 9999?

Comment: What is it in your `println` function? Do you see error messages in the DevConsole?

Comment: I am trying to add the four digits to form a four-digit possible password, so it's not simply 0-9999 though

Comment: Sorry about the tag, I didn't notice it. I will change it

Answer (score 0):

Those nested for loops are really wild and incredibly inefficient. If you want to guess from 0 to 9999, just run the loop through and then pad zeroes to the left.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

```
for (let i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
     let guess = String(i).padStart(4, '0')
     guessAnswer(guess)
     //whatever logic here to exit loop on correct guess
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please mark this answer as correct if it did indeed fix your problem!